# how custom to my needs can a question be

Tags: discussion, questions

As a stackoverflow user, I am having a specific bug that involves a combination of different technologies and i am pretty sure that chances are rather slim that another developer will have the exact same question at some point.

This makes the question of minor importance to the community, right?
Should I go ahead and post this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone else could have the same problem down the line. You never know.

The most important thing is to pose your question in a way that shows you put effort into trying to solve the problem yourself first. Demonstrate what you've tried, post any relevant code involved, link to articles about the problem, etc.

People are generally willing to help you solve your problem if they have knowledge in the subject matter, even if it is a localized problem.

Comment: +1 While others may not have the *same problem,* they may have some that is *sufficiently similar* to the point that they can benefit greatly from the OP's question.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that 20% of the questions on ServerFault are issues that maybe 1 other person in the history of the planet will encounter. Based on this I'd say it's perfectly OK for all the reasons that Jon outlined.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? I personally like this kind of questions - I prefer them over very generic questions which everyone knows the answer to (including Google).

Your part of the deal IMO: If there are very few (or no) people that can answer your highly specific question, then it's fair to also give those people a thumbs up, who are trying to help you without being able to come up with a 100% accurate step-by-step guide (e.g. because they don't have the exact same software/hardware setup on their machine).

Often, a small pointer that goes into the right direction is enough to help solving the rest of the problem on your own. You can then update your post to give an account of how you finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, just give enough detail so someone will be able to help you. And make sure that your question (obscure as it may be) hasn't already been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as it's not already asked and on topic, every question is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely!  You may think it's due to the complex interactions of these various technologies, but someone familiar with even only one of them may find the problem.

Just make sure it's about programming.